# What happens to fields not named by a designated initializer?

Tags: c, initialization, designated-initializer

Since C99 (and C++20), it's possible to initialize structs using this syntax:

```
struct info
{
    char    name[8+1];
    int     sz;
    int     typ;
};

struct info  arr[] =
{
    [0] = { .sz = 20, .name = "abc" },
    [9] = { .sz = -1, .name = "" }
};
```

What happens to the unspecified fields?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that they are 0 initialised. But I'm also sure that someone else will be faster to find the portion of the C99 spec that makes it so. ... And I was right!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

They are zeroed. From the C99 standard §6.7.8 (Initialization)/21,

> If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there are elements or members of an aggregate, or fewer characters in a string literal used to initialize an array of known size than there are elements in the array, **the remainder of the aggregate shall be initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration.**

Comment: Exactly what I wanted to know, complete with standard quote. Thanks!

Comment: @Matt Joiner: Was there ever any doubt? Oh, and for completeness see §6.7.8 (Initialization)/10, which effectively states that such static storage is NULL/0 initialized.

Comment: A useful consequence of this fact is that `{ 0 }` is a universal zero-initializer which can be used for any aggregate type (and actually any type at all, IIRC, though some compilers might give warnings if it's used for simple types).

Comment: @torak I think static duration float point is initialized to +0,thus the original sentence in C99 &sect;6.7.8 is "if it has `arithmetic type`, it is initialized to `(positive or unsigned) zero`;", maybe I am a little pedantic:)?